# 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module when import "@solana/web3.js"

Tags: babeljs, solana

I am going to use solanaweb3 on babelrc project.
When I run `npm start` I am getting [image: this error].
I have gone through many posts on github and stackoverflow.

`npm install -g browserify`
`npm install --save-dev browserify babelify babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-0 babel-preset-env babel-preset-react`
`npm install @babel/core --save`

What is solution?
Here is my `package.json` content.

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "budo src/index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.8",
        "@solana/web3.js": "^1.29.2",
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "babelify": "^10.0.0",
        "browserify": "^16.5.2",
        "budo": "^11.6.4"
    },
    "browserify": {
        "transform": [
            [
                "babelify",
                {
                    "presets": [
                        "@babel/preset-env"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `import` and `export` can be used only inside modules. Maybe try this  `{'type': 'module'}` in your `package.json`